# Finding a match to a string with getline

Tags: c++, match, getline

I am trying to search a vector of string names for matches.  Names can be more than one word so in prompting the user I am using getline(std::cin, name); however I can never find matches with the existing names in the vector.  How do I remove the extra "garbage" from the getline return so it will match with what I have in the vector?

Comment: what kind of `extra garbage` have you seen?

Answer (score 0):

use the delimiter, '\0'.

i.e.:

```
getline(cin, name, '\0');
```

and check this out:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

and this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/